# How to remove all line breaks from text file using Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

I wanted to remove all line breaks from text file
Example:

```
FILE1 +
FILE2 +
FILE3 +
```

The output should be

```
FILE1 + FILE2 + FILE3 +
```

I can't find answers on search engine that can solve my problem that's why I am here to ask this question.

Also is there a way to auto-remove the line break using/from command @echo %SomeStringHere%>>file.txt, because that's the reason I'm having this problem, it automatically insert a line break before the string to insert? Or is there a command that can only update the text file without new line break? Thank you.

Comment: *I wanted to remove all line breaks from text file* What is the max size of those .TXT file? *is there a way to auto-remove the line break using/from command @echo %SomeStringHere%>>file.txt* No.

Comment: There are 3 line breaks.

Thanks a lot, but is there another way that can update the text file without a new line break?

Comment: Batch processing is not suitable for processing text files. For example, all leading/trailing spaces will be removed unconditionally... I'd recommend to use more suitable instrument - VBS for example.

Comment: I would use a Notepad++ macro to do this

Comment: @Akina+ it's a large crock, but CMD can write a variable value (or other string) to a file without adding CRLF by `SET/P ="%var%" >>file <NUL` (or `>` to not append)

Answer (score 0):

test.txt

```
FILE1 +
FILE2 +
FILE3 +
```

join.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set outstring=
for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.txt) do set outstring=!outstring!%%A
echo outstring=%outstring%
```

output

```
c:\Batch>join.bat
outstring=FILE1 + FILE2 + FILE3 +
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing awk. To do this on a OSX

```
brew install awk
```

Once installed you can add the following line to your bash script:

```
awk '{printf "%s+",$0} END {print ""}'
```

Note: If you are using Windows I suggest GAWK (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

Comment: Or just `awk -vORS=+ 1` -- but OP's data appears to already contain the `+` so just `awk -vORS= 1` -- plus `END{print "\n"}` _if desired_ (not clear if it is).